# Use foreach and doParallel to do 1000 times permutation and makeCluster(12), but return warning

Tags: r

```
There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)  

> warnings()  

Warning messages:  

1: closing unused connection 26 (<-localhost:11501)  

2: closing unused connection 25 (<-localhost:11501)  

3: closing unused connection 24 (<-localhost:11501)  

....
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to close connection to the cluster after use. The warning tells you the computer is doing this task for you, and want let you know about it.

Adding this statement `stopCluster(cl)` in the end of your code will "fix" the problem.

Comment: `library(foreach)`    
  `library(doParallel)`     
  `cl <- makeCluster(12)`      
  `registerDoParallel(cl)`
  `myresult <- foreach(i = 1:1000) %dopar% {` 
    `t(apply(inputframe[,sample(1:ncol(inputframe))], 1, functionx))`         
  `}` 
  `return(myresult)`
  `stopImplicitCluster()`  
  `doParallel::stopCluster(cl)`

Comment: Actually, I use two ways to stop since I don't know I should use which one, but I think two is okay to write here since it must have to realize stop. So, I guess it may be not the reason about lack that.